# How Can I print a "dynamic/convergent" array in python

Tags: python, numpy, arraylist, pickle

Well I need the program to be able to export a `.txt` file with the output every time is opened.

I tried with `np.savetxt` & `f.write` and none of them worked in the way I wanted to.

```py
if (index == r): 
    for j in range(r): 
        print(data[j], end = " "); 
        print(); 
    return; 

i = start; 
while(i <= end and end - i + 1 >= r - index): 
    data[index] = arr[i]; 
    combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1, end , index + 1, r); 
    i += 1; 

arr = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 , 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]; 

r = 5; #number of combinations

n = len(arr);
printCombination(arr, n, r);
```

The length of the combinations will change (r), so I need to export an output text file with the results each time the program runs.

Comment: Your code is not syntax correct, did you know that? You can't return from outside of a function. Also offtopic: 1. you don't need a `;` after each statement 2. you don't need `()` for `while`, `if` and `for`. Instead, simply write it like: `while i <= end: do_sth()`

Comment: I format it wrong while re-writing for the platform, also I'm a noobie, thanks for the advice. I'll show you the source of the code so you can take a proper look.[link](https://github.com/Mainframed69/lotto-randomizer/blob/master/Pascal's-Identity-polynomial-time.py)

Comment: can you post the complete code here, since `printCombination` is certainly not defined in this post.

Comment: @knh190 I got it! The way you can print combination utilities is with a "np array" conversion. In this case it'll be something like: np.array = rSubset(arr, r) and then write it with 'np.write()' It worked fine for me no matter the permutations. You should check out the call 'printCombination' since is descendent from 'CombinationUtil'.

Comment: Okay. Great. But I mean, you need to post minimal complete and verifiable code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Your posted code is broken though.